# Does Mac App store provide stack trace for crashes?

Tags: xcode, macos

I am developing an app for mac os x and hoping to publish it in the mac app store. I am wondering if I need to incorporate the stack trace collection mechanisms by myself or does the mac app store will provide the stack trace whenever my application crashes ..

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Every app that you upload through iTunes Connect, being iOS app or Mac app, provides some of the crash reports sent by the users. You can find them in the same place as the iOS apps: Application, View Details, Crash Reports.

Anyway, the crash reports provided by Apple are only a fraction of what your user sent, only updates every 24 hours, and the algorithm for choosing them are opaque. I will recommend you to implement an alternative system to recollect the crash reports from your users. There are several 3rd party solutions both free and paid.

Comment: Thanks, any recommendations on freely available third party solutions ?